# Getting error on .Net Core app "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception"

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application. It uses an ASP.NET Core Web API. The application is running fine when both API and UI are running from Visual Studio 2022.

If I deploy the UI, or both UI and API, to IIS using "No Managed Code" application pool, the application throws an error

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Can anyone assist me in resolving this?

Comment: Well - what **IS** that inner exception?? Remember: we **cannot** see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US** all the relevant information in order for us to be able to help you!

Comment: @marc_s This is all im getting while checking the network tab

Comment: @marc_s nvm i have edited the question

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 There are enough differences that make the self-signed certificates not trusted, as the identity to execute the code changes.

Comment: hi @LexLi Can you share the difference or changes I need to make this work? Since this is happening on local machine, I have created a self signed certificate, binded it to default website and have both API and UI deployed under default website so both uses the same certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow deploying inside Default Web Site on IIS wasn't working. I created a new self signed certificate, deployed both API and UI on the root as a new website with different port for both apps. Enabled https with the newly created self signed certificate on both the applications and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The above error message indicates a problem with SSL certificate validation, the SSL certificate used by your application was not recognized as valid because it was signed by an untrusted certificate authority (CA).

If you are using a self-signed certificate and experiencing SSL verification issues on your local computer, it may be because the certificate is not trusted by default. To resolve this issue, you need to manually add the self-signed certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the local computer. You can try the following steps:

- Open the Run dialog (Win + R), type mmc, and press Enter.
- In the MMC window, go to File > Add/Remove Snap-in...
- Select Certificates from the list of available snap-ins, and click
  Add.
- Select Computer Account, and click Next.
- Select Local Computer and click Finish, then click OK to close the
  Add/Remove Snap-in window.
- Navigate to Certificates (Local Computer) > Trusted Root
  Certification Authorities > Certificates.
- Right-click in the right pane, select All Tasks, and click Import.
- Export the self-signed certificate in advance, and then follow the
  wizard to import the self-signed certificate.

Reference link: [Adding the self-signed certificate as trusted](https://support.kaspersky.com/CyberTrace/3.1/en-US/174127.htm)